# turn array of object into keys failed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this structure

```
  const raw = [{
      date: '2018-8-1',
      devices: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'iphone',
        device_age: 12
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'samsung',
        device_age: 10
      }]
    }, {
      date: '2018-8-2',
      devices: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'iphone',
        device_age: 5
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'samsung',
        device_age: 9
      }]
    }]
```

I want to transform above sturcture into this

```
[{date: '2018-8-1', iphone: 12, samsung: 10}, {date: '2018-8-2', iphone:5, samsung:9}]
```

What's wrong with my attempt below?

```
let result = raw.map((obj, i) => {
   return {
       date: obj.date,
       [obj.devices.map(innerObj => innerObj.name)]: 'test'
   }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q74x8106/

or I shouldn't use map for inner loop? I'm lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `obj.devices.map` returns an array, a computed property name will be coerced into a string or a symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the outer array and build a new object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
const raw = [{ date: '2018-8-1', devices: [{ id: 1, name: 'iphone', device_age: 12 }, { id: 2, name: 'samsung', device_age: 10 }] }, { date: '2018-8-2', devices: [{ id: 1, name: 'iphone', device_age: 5 }, { id: 2, name: 'samsung', device_age: 9 }] }],
    result = raw.map(({ date, devices }) =>
        Object.assign({ date }, ...devices.map(d => ({ [d.name]: d.device_age }))));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: because `Object.assign` combines objects to a single object. you can get the devices as objects with age and get only one object back.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = raw.map((obj, i) => {
    let newObj = {};
    obj.devices.forEach(obj => {
        newObj[obj.name] = obj.device_age

    });
    return {
        date: obj.date,
        ...newObj
    }
})
```